# How to escape special characters in connection string passed to CrmServiceClient constructor

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, xrm-tooling-connector

The `CrmServiceClient` class in the `Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector` namespace has a constructor that takes a connection string as a single argument (documented here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/xrm-tooling/use-connection-strings-xrm-tooling-connect?view=op-9-1).

This connection string is similar/familiar to other uses of connection strings (with name/value pairs separated by equal signs and delimited with semi-colons), but I cannot find any firm documentation to suggest the specific rules for escaping special characters. If in this particular context a connection string value must include an equal sign or semicolon, how is that escaped?  While there is some documentation about SQL and Entity Framework connection strings, those are used in completely different contexts, so I don't see any reason to believe that documentation in those contexts applies to the `CrmServiceClient` constructor context.

Does anyone have a pointer to definitive documentation for this context, and/or sufficient experience *in this context* to venture a fairly definitive ad hoc description?

Thanks.

===========================ADDED IN RESPONSE TO REQUEST IN COMMENT

In the comments to the initial question above, a kind contributor requested that I add more detail about my user story.  The request was that I add my own builder/parser.

I will not be creating a parser.  The parser will be the one used by the `CrmServiceClient` constructor.  It is part of the Xrm Tooling Connector.

I have not yet created a builder to build the connection string that will be passed to the `CrmServiceClient` constructor.  And my first task will be to create a unit test for that builder that will determine whether it was built correctly or not, which is why I would like the definitive rules enforced by the parser.

Take the following example connection string:

`AuthType=OAuth;Username=jsmith@contoso.onmicrosoft.com; Password=passcode;Url=https://contosotest.crm.dynamics.com;AppId=51f81489-12ee-4a9e-aaae-a2591f45987d; RedirectUri=app://58145B91-0C36-4500-8554-080854F2AC97;LoginPrompt=Auto`

In this basic example, there is no value anywhere in the set of key/value pairs of the connection string that has any special characters in it, so nothing needs escaping.  But now let us imagine that the Password is not the string "passcode", but instead is full of special characters.  Let us say that the password is

`"aB4$;";~^''dEfg'!`

That password itself starts with a double quotation mark, has another double quotation mark in it, has two single quotation marks and two semicolons.  It is not unreasonable to expect that a password might have characters like this.  If the connection string passed to the `CrmServiceClient` constructor is exactly this:

`AuthType=OAuth;Username=jsmith@contoso.onmicrosoft.com; Password="aB4$;";~^''dEfg'!;Url=https://contosotest.crm.dynamics.com;AppId=51f81489-12ee-4a9e-aaae-a2591f45987d; RedirectUri=app://58145B91-0C36-4500-8554-080854F2AC97;LoginPrompt=Auto`

Then for sure it will be parsed incorrectly.

This is the problem I am trying to solve with a set of definitive rules used by the `CrmServiceClient` constructor parser.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did it work?

Comment: I am needing to write a somewhat-universal connection-string-builder, which will itself take parameters (AKA values) related to different keys and then generate a connection string from that.  I can of course throw spaghetti against that wall and try lots of things, but a clearly defined set of rules to which I can write my unit test suite would be very helpful.

Comment: connection string is just a string, the consumer library is responsible for build/parse it. why do you, as a user of the library, so care about the format?

Comment: @LeiYang - I am aware of this.  But if the connection string has a password in it, and that password has a semicolon in it, then that semicolon will tell the connection string parser that the value is over unless it is escaped somehow.  Also values that start or end with spaces or key names that have equal signs.... these are all issues that need to be escaped.  This is a well-known issue generally, but I see no specific documentation for the rules and conventions as applied to the connection string used as a `CrmServiceClient` constructor argument.

Comment: when you talk about escape, what actually do you mean? do you mean escape in xml?

Comment: @LeiYang - I'm not sure how to be more clear.  XML has its own needs to escape special characters that have meaning to the xml parser.  Connection strings are also parsed, and they are parsed based on special characters that have meaning to the connection string parser.  If characters that have meaning to the connection string parser must be inside of values that should remain unparsed, there needs to be some way to quote or escape them.  But of course if you are quoting them, then the quote characters need some way to be escaped, and so on.

Comment: can you edit you question to add some **user stories/use cases** of your own builder/parser?

Comment: @LeiYang - please see edits to initial question.

Answer (score 1):

Inferred, but not documented and guaranteed answer:

I decompiled the XRM Toolkit code, and the constructor in question.  It does appear that very far under the hood, the same parser is being used that Microsoft uses for connection strings for databases and the like, in `System.Data`.

In addition, there is a public (but undocumented) extension method that will take a `CrmServiceClient` connection string as an argument and return a `Dictionary<string,string>` of the the key/value pairs parsed out of the connection string.  That method is:  `Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.Extension.ToDictionary()`.

From using that method, I can determine that the following works as ONE set of defacto rules that can be used for building connection strings:

1. Connection string values MAY always be enclosed in single quotes.
2. If the connection string value is to have any special characters in it, it MUST be surrounded by single quotes.  (NB - double quotes are also acceptable, but I am using single quotes for my purposes.)
3. Special characters definitely include leading and trailing whitespace, semicolon, and single quotes.  This list may not be exhaustive.
4. If you need to include a single quote inside a connection string value, you must double it to escape it.

Comment: looks like reverse engineering

Comment: Yes, that is why I don't like it particularly.  I would rather have official documentation not inferred reverse engineering.